# Bridging header file does not exist error

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I am trying to duplicate and rename my Xcode project, however I keep running into this error:

> bridging header '/Users/user/Documents/Developer/App Name/App Name-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist

I have checked to ensure that the file actually exists, and I don't see any reason why this would be an issue given that the project was duplicated, so it shouldn't be any different?

Anyone have any ideas? I was wondering if it's anything to do with the fact that I'm using CocoaPods?

Comment: So the file does actually exist?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed.

Comment: same problem here. As well after project "duplication" (Actually, new target within same project). File exists. odd